# What colors do orks believe have magical effects?

Tags: warhammer-40k

We all know that ork vehicles are faster when painted red.  Do the orks have beliefs about other colors?

Comment: I don't know enough to make it an answer but apparently yellow bombs make bigger explosions.

Comment: Not sure how official the information in this is, but gives some insight https://1d4chan.org/wiki/Colorz

Answer (score 9):

A common answer to this is:

> Green is best because Orks are green.
>
> Blue is lucky.
>
> Black is dead 'ard.
>
> White is deadly.
>
> Purple is sneaky because you've never seen a purple ork.
>
> Yellow is flashy, both with explosions and with fancy gubbins.

But the canonicity of this answer is suspect. I have found what seems to be a reliable source for one more color though:

Blue is lucky.

> Deathskulls: Lucky Blue Gitz
>
> All Orks believe blue to be a lucky color...
>
> [An except from the Ork codex, via spikeybits.com](https://spikeybits.com/2018/10/orktober-at-an-end-gws-ork-codex-latest-updates-more.html)

I don't have direct access to actual source material to look for more. As far as I can tell, the usual quote on the subject might be an exaggeration or describing clans that tend to use that color rather any widespread ork belief about the color itself. The explanations for black and yellow on the [1d4chan page](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/Colorz) do seem at least plausible to me though.

Answer (score 7):

From [1D4chan article on colorz](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/Colorz):

> Red
>
> Objects or beings that are red go faster. Red can also be described as brutal since going faster helps get into melee. The most well-known and memetic color, because "Red goes fasta." Believed to have started as a reference to the first "Gundam" anime of all things. Red is also associated with relatively disciplined and tactical Orks. It is the color of Kommandos and the Blood Axes clan, who both use advanced tactics such as ambushes, unit organization, and cover.
>
> Blue
>
> Blue things are lucky. This goes both for safety and gain. Blue is also cunning, and in Fantasy represents magic itself as well as the physical protection that magic warpaint brings to Savage Orcs. The Gnoblar army Gnoblar Horde: The Unwashed Masses used it to differentiate an entire type of soldier separate from other Gnoblar, the Lucky Gits.
>
> Blood
>
> Existing only in Gnoblar lore, Blood-Gnoblars are rangers and trackers that are far smarter than other Greenskins, at least in terms of survival skills and a disturbing amount of common sense. Originally they were a subrace of Greenskin with red and brown skin, but common green Gnoblar wanting to join them began killing things and painting themselves in blood.
>
> Green
>
> The best, because it is their own natural skin color. Anything can be improved with green, even if other colors actually add powers. Fantasy greenskins may paint their non-greenskin allies like Giants and Ogres green to help them be Orcy while Orks paint their human allies, the Diggaz, green as well. Any attempt at diplomacy should involve the color green.
>
> Yellow
>
> Wealth, although not because of gold; Orc/ks use Teef (teeth) as currency, and their teeth yellow fast. Orks also believe yellow produces better explosions, while Orcs do have a slight value for precious metals although they mostly just pile it up as a luck totem to bring better loot and Teef (it works).
>
> White
>
> Death, like bones. White is dangerous, and can have multiple meanings although generally it means fearlessness and intent to kill.
>
> Black
> Toughness. Black Orcs get their name as a description (that and the fact their metal armor tends to be tarnished and blackened) rather than the color their bodies are due to this.
>
> Camouflage
>
> Regardless if it actually matches the environment, greenskins who think they have camo on will actually seem near invisible. Likewise they may not register camo that they see.
>
> Checkerboard
>
> Checkerboard patterns, usually white and black, can mean a connection to Gork and Mork (or was it Mork and Gork?), increased physical prowess, or is a means of showing allegiance; in 40k checker patterns mark an Ork as belonging to the Goff Klan (clan) but in Fantasy the meaning is less clear. The Beast Arises series had a group of Orks infiltrating a Black Templar ship having Luna Wolves Black and White armor, later on a human hypothesizes that the Orks remember the Luna Wolves conquering Ullanor and regard the Luna Wolves' colors as a sign of toughness. It could also be that the Orks had the belief before the Luna Wolves came, but that the armor matched their kulture's belief. A popular meme is that it is Orc/k camo attempts with white being daytime camo and black as nighttime camo.

1d4chan usually describes lore in a funny way but they're usually rather accurate on the topic.